# AngularJS IE8 and lower library error

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, object, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

IE developer tools selects this when debugging:

```
return e.apply?function(){var a=[];q(arguments,function(b){a.push(d(b))});return e.apply(b,a)}:function(a,b){e(a,null==b?"":b)}
```

and the error says: Object doesn't support this action

Only ie8 and lower, please help, i tried multiple versions of angular same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS team states that [they are testing in IE8](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), so it should work fine.

This is all I can tell from those minimal details you have shared. I suspect the problem is not in the AngularJS code, but somewhere in your code. You are passing some kind of argument into the function this line is from, and that argument is causing the problem.

Sorry, cannot tell you more without more details.